# Merkle tree hash - Computing hash manually doesnt match the one computed by SHA256D64

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, hash, merkle-tree, sha256

I am trying to go through the code to check the merkle tree hash computation done by `BlockMerkleRoot` in **bitcoin core**. The hash computed using online tools by appending transaction hashes is different from the ones computed by `SHA256D64` of `BlockMerkleRoot`. I am sure I am missing something. Could someone throw light on this?

**Details:**
Looking at block **[500000](https://bitaps.com/500000?page=1)**:

appending coinbase hash *2157b554dcfda405233906e461ee593875ae4b1b97615872db6a25130ecc1dd6* with the first transaction hash *fe6c48bbfdc025670f4db0340650ba5a50f9307b091d9aaa19aa44291961c69f* and computing [sha256](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html) gives *0387276cdb563dc923e945f8e68596e3556756d2f2119b9b67905658b73afcb2* and doing another sha256 gives *1c0a7630e70d2b39b15585ec19c13c6f0a729a6501f5396dd75f75cb3aa4d110* which is different from the one returned by `SHA256D64` which is *1024e63a6bdab1efb75aae1dd065c11a97cf94e978e6aed9adb2f04d08887164*.

Answer (score 0):

The tool you are linking to is hashing *text*, Bitcoin hashes are of *bytes*.

Comment: I used hex version in the tool

Comment: I used shasum and I get a different result :) I am definitely missing something fundamental.

```
x@instance1:~/backup$ echo -n 2157b554dcfda405233906e461ee593875ae4b1b97615872db6a25130ecc1dd6fe6c48bbfdc025670f4db0340650ba5a50f9307b091d9aaa19aa44291961c69f|xxd -r -p | shasum -b | awk '{print $1}'

41ca9dd2793aa443509251d3c90f1a3669d1b65e

x@instance1:~/backup$ echo -n 41ca9dd2793aa443509251d3c90f1a3669d1b65e |xxd -r -p | shasum -b | awk '{print $1}'

54daec3b996b6fcd0d04f70bdac2067b86e44e55

x@instance1:~/backup$

```

Answer (score 0):

The strings you posted are technically transaction *IDs* not transaction *hashes* and have to be reversed to get that "actual hash". In bitcoin when hashes are printed as strings they are reversed. The actual hashes you should use are `d61dcc0e13256adb725861971b4bae753859ee61e406392305a4fddc54b55721`|`9fc661192944aa19aa9a1d097b30f9505aba500634b04d0f6725c0fdbb486cfe` When this is hashed twice it gives the following result: `647188084df0b2add9aee678e994cf971ac165d01dae5ab7efb1da6b3ae62410` since we print hashes in reverse it becomes "1024...7164" which is what you got from `SHA256D64`.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. The `GetHex` is doing the reverse of the hash to be printed using `ToString`. May I know the rationale behind why the transaction ID/`ToString` is reverse of the actual transaction hash?

Comment: I suppose this is the case for blockhash as well, which is `00000000000000000024fb37364cbf81fd49cc2d51c09c75c35433c3a1945d04` . If this is byte reversed to get the "actual hash", it starts with `045d..0000`. How does `CheckProofOfWork` work? How is this "actual hash" less than the target difficulty set for the block? I see `UintToArith256` copying word by word without much change other than endian-ness. Could you please provide clarity?

Comment: I got part of the answer [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5201170.0)

Comment: The reason is this: SHA256 outputs a byte array, but in early versions of the Bitcoin software, that byte array was interpreted as a number - in little endian (least significant digit first). In the RPC output, those numbers are printed for human consumption in hex, with the most significant digit first (which matters; otherwise, block hashes would have their 0s at the end, which wouldn't look like "small" numbers).